# Sickness expressions

Tags: grammar

Why when we have a fever we say

> I have a fever.

But when I have diarrhea we say

> I have diarrhea.

Why don't we say

> I have a diarrhea.

Is there any rule? If I come across a new symptom, how do I decide whether to add "a" or not adding it into my sentence?

Comment: Why are the names of the disease all in small letters?

Comment: They aren't proper names. But for example *Parkinson's disease* would because it was named for someone.

Comment: See more discussion of a closely related question at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82976/i-got-a-stomach-flu-or-i-got-the-stomach-flu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have **diarrhea**.

is correct. Disease names do not use an article (for example cancer, diabetes, hepatitis, pneumonia, etc).

> I have **a fever**.

Descriptive conditions do (for example headache, broken arm, strained back, etc.)

Comment: The patient complained of early fatigue, cardiac discomfort and palpitation. (descriptive conditions? )

Comment: Perhaps the patient had the mumps.  Or the measles.  Or the Spanish flu.  (In most case the dichotomy presented in this answer is correct, but there are exceptions.)

Comment: The exceptions you spotted almost always swing both ways. "I had mumps" et alis, is also correct. ("I have a cancer" is a bit archaic, but also valid.) (See V.V.'s answer)  "A lesion" vs. "lesions" seems to be the general rule with exceptions for things like named diseases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a rule.With a plural (countable) noun you should use an article. The first noun is countable in this meaning (if you aren't sure,consult a good dictionary).The second noun is a mass noun.You don't need an article here.